# json values not parsing in ajax

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I could not pass my json values to the url

```
var url="http://192.168.2.143/php/welcome.php";

 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: url,
 data: ({fname:"hi",age:"21"}),
 success: success,
 error:function(e)
 {
         alert(e);
 }

});


 }

 function success()
 {
         alert("done");
 }
```

Well if I change the url to  `welcome.php` its not working. I have `welcome.php` in my folder , i want to access it from another system so i changed the url,
thank u in advance.

Comment: You cannot make cross domain AJAX request. Only requests to the same domain are allowed for security reasons.

Comment: oh , then wats the solution for it , i want it by any means , can u suggest any other way of doin it @Lex

Comment: Is your server on the same LAN ? 192.168.2.143 is a local address, not an internet one. Are you sure you don't have firewall problems ?

Comment: 192.168.2.143 is a computer next to me , i guess its not having any fire wall block @dystroy

Comment: You cannot do cross domain AJAX calls. If you want this to work you could use JSONP if you have control over the remote script that you are trying to call. But the jquey implementation of JSONP doesn't support POST method, only GET.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov even i tried jsonp it aint working , i am always taken to error call back and also changed the method to get

Comment: This code works and gives you the `alert` if you remove that pesky curly brace. It throws the error - alerting `[object Object]`. Run it in your console

Comment: How did you try JSONP? Did you modify your `welcome.php` script to return JSONP instead of JSON?

Comment: You can make a script that is called by AJAX on the same domain that does an HTTP request to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra curly brace

```
 } // HERE

function success()
{
     alert("done");
}
```